# How to replace /root/.ssh/authorized_keys with cloud-config on EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

When deploying a new EC2 instance you have to select an SSH key to give access to the machine. I would like to use *only* the authorised keys specified in the user data for an instance. Is this possible? I've tried using both `ssh-authorized-keys`:

```
users:
  - name: user
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa [...] my_key
```

and `write_files`:

```
write_files:
  - content: |
        ssh-rsa [...] my_key
    path: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

, but in both cases the original key is added to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` automatically. Do I need to disable `root` login to disable this key permanently?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you post a snippet of your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user *ec2-user|centos|ubuntu*... is the **default_user** as defined by /etc/cloud/*.cfg

This is how to skip this default_user behaviour, and setup another user by the user-data:

```
#cloud-config
system_info:
  default_user: ~
users:
- name: myname
  sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
  ssh-authorized-keys:
  - ssh-rsa AAAA[...]O1 myname@myhost
```

Please note that the keypair selected on AWS console/api is ignored.

Comment: I don't have the opportunity to test this myself anymore, but marking this as accepted since it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching an instance from AWS web console, you can choose to launch without a key in the final step. Thus, only the public key you specify in cloud-config will be injected into the instance.

[image: Choosing key pair]